# Truffle Test: Setting blockTime

Tags: web3js, truffle, ganache, truffle-test, ganache-cli

I'm using Truffle and I want to increase the blocktime to mimic that of the mainnet when i run my tests.

As i understand it, Truffle has already instantiated a web3 instance that's ready to use so i tried to modify it with the following in my test file:

```js
const ganache = require('ganache-core')
web3.setProvider(ganache.provider({ blockTime: 15 }))
```

However each test finishes in less than 200ms.

How would i go about changing the blocktime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply start Ganache with `-b 15`.

See [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli#command-line) for more details.

**Update:**

The above solution is for when you start Ganache as a separate process.

In order to simulate a 15-second elpase in your tests, you can simply use this:

```
web3.currentProvider.send({method: "evm_increaseTime", params: [15]});
```

Comment: Firing up Ganache in a separate process with the `-b 15` flag worked, now each test takes just over 15000ms. However the second solution gave me
`before each hook: setup contract for each test: Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function`

Comment: @Conviley: The above works in Truffle 4.x, which relies on web3.js v0.x. It might require a different syntax if you're on Truffle 5.x, which relies on web3.js v1.x.

Comment: Okay i'm using truffle v5.1.13 so that might be the reason then.

Comment: @Conviley were you able to figure it out?